# What is the prime factorization $6+12i \in \Bbb Z[i]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, gaussian-integers

> What is the prime factorization $6+12i \in \Bbb Z[i]$?

I'm reading an abstract algebra sheet where they had the following problem, but I cannot find any examples on irreducible elements of $\Bbb Z[i]$. If I understand the problem correclty I'm being asked to express $6+12i$ as a product of irreducible elements of $\Bbb Z[i]$?

Comment: Do you know how to characterize the irreducibles in $\mathbb Z[i]?$

Comment: Clearly, $2$ and $3$ are factors, so this reduces the problem to finding factors of $1 + 2i$.

Comment: @Dan 2 is not prime, it factors as $(1+i)(1-i)$

Comment: Are $2$ and $3$ both irreducible? @Dan

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No. This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @SleepWalker Well, that isn't the question you asked.

Comment: You can reason with norm (or squared norm), that's easier.

Answer (score 3):

To start, it's clear that we can factor out a $6$, which is $2\times 3$. Thus:

$$6+12i=2\times 3\times \left(1+2i\right)$$

Of these three factors, $3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, because it cannot be written as a sum of two squares. Also, $\left(1+2i\right)$ is irreducible, because its norm is $5$, which is prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand, since $2$ can be written as a sum of two squares ($2=1+1$), we can factor it in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$: $2=\left(1+i\right)\left(1-i\right)$.

Thus, a full factorization looks like:

$$6+12i = 3\times\left(1+i\right)\times\left(1-i\right)\times\left(1+2i\right)$$

Each of the four factors on the right is irreducble